# What's the best way of attaching an on-click event to a table cell?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5

I am trying to attach an on-click event to a table cell so when its clicked its background changes colour and text saying 'Yes' appears in the middle. I would also like it to fire a PHP method in a controller class.

I have code such as the following:

// index.html

```

```
<table>
    <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>Heading</th>
   </tr>
   <thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr class="clickme">
   <td><a onclick="reserve();return false;" href={{route('submitaction', 
   $colour->colour_id) }}</a></td> // On click, change its background 
   colour.
   <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

// scripts.js

```
function reserve(){

 $(this).addClass('newColour');

}
```

//flow.live.css

```
   .newColour {
    background-color: gray;
    content: 'Yes';
    text-align: center;
    }
```

I am going to pad the link to fill the entire table cell and have the event fire when the user clicks the link. Is what I am trying to do sensible and are there any other clever work-arounds?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I have used a different markup, because you did not provide the CSS.

What you need is to delegate the event to the parent element.

I have used this markup from another website:

```
<table id="customers">
<tr>
<th>Company</th>
<th>Contact</th>
<th>Country</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
<td>Maria Anders</td>
<td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
<td>Christina Berglund</td>
<td>Sweden</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
<td>Francisco Chang</td>
<td>Mexico</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ernst Handel</td>
<td>Roland Mendel</td>
<td>Austria</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Island Trading</td>
<td>Helen Bennett</td>
<td>UK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Königlich Essen</td>
<td>Philip Cramer</td>
<td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
 <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
 <td>Canada</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
 <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
 <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>North/South</td>
  <td>UK</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Paris spécialités</td>
<td>Marie Bertrand</td>
<td>France</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$( "#customers" ).on( "click", "td", function( event ) { // target the outermost parent element, this will delegate the event to the element specified as second arg on the callback function
$(this).addClass('newColour'); // Here you just add the class, no inline JS needed.

 });
```

That is it, read about event delegation and why it is useful and try the working code here, there is no PHP code, but your biggest issue was the JS.:

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/JwZXya